How do I link a SmartCard for Wallix Bastion?
How do I use a winkeo card as a 2FA to access to the Bastion : I want to let the user connect to the Bastion with the smartcard pin and then the bastion (using same creds) jump to a win server behind it
To do so : I have in my labs a wallix bastion v10 and a winserver 2016 and dc 2016. Contacted the support to ask how do I implement a Winkeo card as a 2FA. They guided me for the conf in wallix. Now the bastion is corretly configured and I have the driver to read the winkeo.
But I can't seem to find where do I have to make the link ?
Can someone help
Thanks !
